# Revert effect of source $VIMRUNTIME\mswin.vim

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

On Windows, Vim does `source $VIMRUNTIME\mswin.vim` in its system-wide config and remaps many keys.

I'd like to have default Vim key bindings but I don't want to touch system-wide config. How do I do it in proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top of the file checks the variable `g:skip_loading_mswin` which you can set to prevent it from running. Put this in your vimrc:

```
let g:skip_loading_mswin = 1
```

Comment: I didn't know that my `vimrc` is loaded before system-wide `vimrc`. That worked, thanks. It was (hopefully) the last time when I used Ctrl+V to paste text in Vim.